# Given positive parameters $a,b$ how can one tell when a Hopf Bifurcation occurs?

Tags: nonlinear-system

Consider the system

$\frac{dx}{dt}$=$2-(b+1)x+ax^{2}y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}$=$bx-ax^{2}y$

For what values of a and b does a Hopf Bifurcation occure, given that a and b are positive, and in the region x,y ≥0

I found that the system had only one fixed point (2,$\frac{b}{2a}$) and computed the jacobian at that point. Should I be looking for eigenvalues here and figuring out for what values of a, b different fixed points occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find that the Jacobian of this system has two complex eigenvalues (which are complex conjugates of each other) at the fixed point which you have correctly found. A Hopf bifurcation occurs when a fixed point loses stability. That means it happens when the real part of the eigenvalues goes from negative (stable) to positive (unstable). Since you have the eigenvalues as a function of $a$ and $b$, you can calculate a relationship between $a$ and $b$ when that real part is zero, which is where the Hopf bifurcation occurs.

Comment: So would it be possible to find set values for a and b or would it suffice to say a Hopf Bifurcation occurs when b=4a+1 because that's when the real part equals to zero.

Comment: I think the latter, although I don't get that the condition is $b = 4a+1$. I get $1 + 4 a + b = 2 a^2 b$.